# Observer Pattern : How to differentiate Observables

Tags: java, observer-pattern

In a swing application, text box 1 depends on combo box 1's selected item. It also depends on Text Box 2's text.Like this, the text box 1 may depend on a variety of components. For all these changes, text box 1's update() method is called (following Observable Pattern rules). How to distinguish as to which component has changed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're describing here.   Are you keeping your application domain data in the UI layer or something?

Comment: No. no. I'm following MVC. But I just explained it in short. Basically, I have subscribed to 10 news channels/feeds. Whenever there is a new news item in any of those feeds, I want to be notified. That's observer pattern right? But now I want to be able to identify as to which news feed has actually changed. Coz maybe if it is from news channel 1, I might want to display it in black, if its from news channel 2, i want to display it in blue... i hope i could make it clear.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to re-write your question to make it more closely reflect what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understood you. But I think that the observer pattern is the wrong choice, the observer pattern solves busy waiting problems, and notifies many object that the subject (the observable) has change, and not vice versa. You could bend the patterns rules and make the observers send a message to the subject that they have changed, but that would not be the observer pattern anymore.

Note: When dealing with design patterns, always look at what they solve, because the way to implement is in many cases so close, that its impossible to distinguish them from the code.

Comment: I'll explain it. I have subscribed to 10 news channels/feeds. Whenever there is a new news item in any of those feeds, I want to be notified. That's observer pattern right? But now I want to be able to identify as to which news feed has actually changed. Coz maybe if it is from news channel 1, I might want to display it in black, if its from news channel 2, i want to display it in blue... i hope i could make it clear.

Comment: It's clear, and not observer pattern. The observer pattern gives you the opposite, many get notified when one special object changes. You just described the opposite. So just make a 'manager' function, that gets an integer\Enum identifying who has changed, and it calls the appropriate function. There might be a design pattern for that - but I don't know it.

Comment: FYI: According to your title, you got the names wrong. It's like this: Subject - the one everyone listens to; Observer - someone that is listening to the subject.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you implement your observer, generally you would provide the 'sender' or component firing the event.

Doing so..though your Textbox1 subscribes to 3 events..it can check who the sender/component 
is.

Comment: I'm not looking for that. That way if there is a possibility to have 10 senders, I would have to use 10 instanceof or 10 if blocks to check the sender

Comment: Or switch statement.  I wonder then if you really need to know the sender.  Say for example textbox1's value depends on 10 other elements..can you create a updateTextBox() that surveys the 10 elements/calculates the value;  Textbox1 would only be concerned w an update/changed event.